# How to pass multiple Time Matrix (N*N) to optaplanner

Tags: optaplanner

I want to make the route timing (arrival) updated with the current traffic in the city.So I fetched Multiple Time Matrix from Google API.Now while routing the Arrival time should be calculated from the Matrix fetched for that time Interval.
For Example : I have fetched 3 Time Matrix. 10:00 {N * N} 12:00 {N * N} and 14:00{N * N}
If previousCustomer's arrival time is 11:00 then for next customer the time should be fetched from Matrix 12:00{}.

So How could I do this using Optaplanner ?
Let me know if anyone one need more explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using that matrix from OptaPlanner isn't hard. Just refactor `RoadLocation.getDistanceTo(RoadLocation)` to something like `RoadLocation.getDistanceTo(RoadLocation, LocalDateTime startingTime)` and adjust your score rules accordingly.

The big problem is **memory while scaling out**. If you have 10k locations, then only 1 time interval already costs almost 2GB RAM memory...